# Is it ok to use the original-source meta tag for pages that are not news

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I am building an online shop for selling products manufactured by others.

Should I use the `original-source` meta tag to give credit for the product (or product info) to the original manufacturer or is this tag intended to be used only for news ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's ok.

It seems to be really related to Google News. And I don't think your content to be listed in Google News since it's an online shop.

In [the presentation article](http://googlenewsblog.blogspot.fr/2010/11/credit-where-credit-is-due.html), Google describe `original-source` meta tag as *a metatag for Google News*.

Also, regarding the [help center article](http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?answer=191283), it clearly identify these tags to *highlight standout journalism on the web*.